# Corba: org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextStub cannot be cast to org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExt

Tags: java, naming, corba

I want to build an object hierarchy over the CORBA namespace and I tried this tutorial

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlNaming.html

I successfully compiled  NameClient.java, started orbd on localhost then ran the test.
It failed with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextStub cannot be cast to org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExt
        at NameClient.main(NameClient.java:24)
```

The source code for the NameClient class:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.*;

public class NameClient
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "1050");
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
        ORB orb = ORB.init(args, props);
        NamingContextExt ctx =
          NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references(
            "NameService"));
        org.omg.CORBA.Object objref = ctx;

        NameComponent name1[] = ctx.to_name("plans");
        ctx.rebind(name1, objref);
        System.out.println("plans rebind successful!");

        NameComponent name2[] = ctx.to_name("Personal");
        NamingContextExt ctx2 = (NamingContextExt)ctx.bind_new_context(name2);
        System.out.println("New naming context, Personal, added!");

        NameComponent name3[] = ctx.to_name("schedule");
        ctx2.rebind(name3, objref);
        System.out.println("schedule rebind successful!");

        NameComponent name4[] = ctx.to_name("calendar");
        ctx2.rebind(name4, objref);
        System.out.println("calendar rebind successful!");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }  
}
```

Isn't this example suppose to work ? Any idea how to get passed this error ?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please provide the actual code you are trying to run.  (Yea I know, you copied it out of the tutorial.  Just do it anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used corba was a few years back. As I recall the idea is to stay away from naked Java "cast" operator, the recommended way to cast a CORBA Object was(is?) to use the target type's "Helper" method to narrow name2 to ctx2. I recommend

```
    NameComponent name2[] = ctx.to_name("Personal");
    NamingContextExt ctx2 = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(name2);

    not

    NamingContextExt ctx2 = (NamingContextExt)ctx.bind_new_context(name2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: Echo is your service interface which has logic

```
            org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
            NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
            Echo href = EchoHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str("ECHO-SERVER"));

            String hello = href.echoString();
            System.out.println(hello);
```